# Representation Theorem for functionals of Continuous Semimartingales

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, reference-request, stochastic-calculus

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be Probability space and let $\{(X_t) : 0 \leq t \leq T \}$ be a continuous semimartingale on it. Let $\xi$ be $\mathcal{F}_T^X$ measurable. Does it mean that $\xi =  F(X_u : 0 \leq u \leq T)$ for some measurable $F : C[0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ? Here the topology on $C[0,T]$ is generated by cylindrical sets. Intuitively the answer seems to be yes. I attempted to prove it by assuming that $\xi$ only depends on $X$ at finite number of times. However, I have problems passing to the limit. Any help/references is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is true even without the assumption that $X$ is a semimartingale.

This is an important feature of the cylindrical topology, and this is why it is used in stochastic processes theory.

Comment: If you are interested in a theorem more associated to semimartingale theory and stochastic calculus, what you want is probably a martingale representation theorem. For example, if the filtration is generated by a Brownian motion $W$, then any $\xi\in\mathcal{F}_t$ which is square-integrable with mean zero satisfies $X = \int_0^t H_s dW_s$ for some suitable process $H$.

Comment: @mookid: Can you please provide reference for the proof. Thanks

Comment: @AlexanderSokol : Yes, I am interested also in that question. Please look here - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/999383/ito-integral-representation-for-bounded-claims If you have any answer for it, I would love to hear. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Fix $T>0$ and let $\zeta = (X_t)_{t\le T}$, it then holds that $\zeta$ is a measurable mapping from $\Omega$ to $C[0,T]$. By conventional measure theory results, we then also obtain that $\mathcal{F}_T^X$ is generated by the single variable $\zeta$, $\mathcal{F}^X_T = \sigma(\zeta)$. Therefore, by the Doob-Dynkin lemma (see the first lemma of Section A.IV.3 of "Classical potential theory and its probabilistic counterpart" by J. L. Doob), it holds that there exists a measurable mapping $F:C[0,T]\to\mathbb{R}$ with the property that $\xi =F(\zeta) = F((X_t)_{t\le T})$, as required.